# Space between characters in php form

Tags: php, web, spacing

```
<?php
        ini_set( display_errors, 1 );
        error_reporting( E_ALL );
        $email = $_POST['myEmail'];
        $name = $_POST['myName'];
        $news = $_POST['news'];

        if($news != 'Yes') 
        $news = 'No';  

        $to = "web@myemail.com";
        $subject = "Add me to the Launch Day Notification List!";
        $headers = "From:".$email;
        $txt = "This person wishes to be added to the launch day notification list".$name <br>
        "Does this person wish to subscribe to the newsletter?".$news;
        mail($to,$subject,$headers,$txt);
        echo "Thank you for your inquiry, you will be added to our launch day notification list!";
?>
```

My problem is on the $txt section I'd like spacing at between the $name and $news and the last characters of the sentences. But also, how do I add a break between the two questions so they output as follows:

This person wishes to be added to the launch day notification list: name here
Does this person wish to subscribe to the newsletter? yes or no here

Comment: You're talking about space but use line break. You're missing concatenating and opening quote here ".$name <br>. But if you're talking about space then use space. If it's line break it will be \r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a space like this

```
$txt = "This person wishes to be added to the launch day notification list $name<br>Does this person wish to subscribe to the newsletter? $news";
```

If you are not sending HTML email you should replace the `<br>` with `"\n"` like

```
$txt = "This person wishes to be added to the launch day notification list $name\nDoes this person wish to subscribe to the newsletter? $news";
```

Comment: The weirdest concat i have ever seen

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski Yea, minor hiccup on the brain engagement front :)